# JUnit: What to Assert on Hibernate Save

Tags: hibernate, junit, junit4

I am new to JUnit and trying to implement it in my legacy codebase.
What should I assert when I test `hibernateEntity.save()`?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to test [Session.save()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#save(java.lang.Object))?

Comment: Could you post the save() method?

Answer (score 2):

You will be calling hibernateEntity.save() inside a method. 
 Like this :

```
public boolean save(..){
  boolean status = false;
  try{
    status = hibernateEntity.save()?
  }catch(Exception e){
     //handle or throw
  } 
 return status;
}
```

So to test save method; you will do assertion on its returned value. So for successful saving its returned value should be true.

So basically; we test the behavior with Junit. You need to test if the hibernate operation was successful or not.

Comment: If hibernateEntity was returning anything I could have Asserted based on return value. As I mentioned earlier I am writing test cases for legacy code. Can not change save method for each entity.

Comment: Yes; you can do that as well. I just gave an example to illustrate my point. Idea is that you should return a value.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is

```
public void testEntitySave() {
  hibernateEntity.save()

Entity testEntity = hibernateEntity.loadEntityByPK(hibernateEntity.pk);

Assert.assertNotNull(testEntity);

}
```

Comment: I agree with this general idea; just keep in mind that this is a very basic level of testing. A better test coverage would include creating/editing an Entity and then Assert.assertEquals( expectedEntity, actualEntity).